# My latex documents takes longer to compile , freezes for a while black but then continues to compile and takes longer

Tags: pdftex, compiling, ubuntu

I am a bit new to latex, I am using ubuntu 14.04. My document was running very fine, after i think after i added glossaries i face this problem. help will be appreciated. Following is  main.tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.9in,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
%================ package for clickable reference%=========

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%============= Package of Accroyns============

\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\input{glossary}


%===================table packages=============%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

%======================Math package========================%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

%= Package for bullents indents spacing and sping betwen bullets ==
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

%================= BIBLIOGRAPHY AND REFRENCES PACKGES %
\usepackage[]{natbib}

%==============Header and footer stuff============%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[re]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

%============Sub and SUperscript package==================
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

%==================== GRAPHICS PREAMBLE %====================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }


%==========Todonotes package============
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\ToDoMG}[1]{\todo[inline,size=\small]{MG: #1}}
\usepackage{longtable}

% Hyphenation
\hyphenation{phe-ro-mo-ne}
\newcommand{\comp}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Acronyms}

%***************************************************
% Document
%---------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code to provide us with a minimal example which demonstrates the problem you are experiencing. This should contain a probably reduced preamble - only what's necessary - and just enough content to allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If you compile on the command line, you can see what is printed to the console at the point when the freeze occurs.

Comment: @cfr console shows log file, it does not show anything specific.

Comment: Yes, but if you watch it, you can see what it is doing when it freezes e.g. running `xindy`. If you just look in the log, you can't tell that.

Comment: @cfr When i start my texmaker and run compile the main.tex and it shows my pdf and the current page that appears is from the second chapter. I mean it should start with the title page. It jumps to the 2nd chapter directly, is it normal too. Please help

Comment: Er ... what? I suggested compiling on the command line to observe where it stops ....

Comment: The document in your question does not have a second chapter. So we don't have the document you are using. How can we help you if we don't even have your document?

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
```

This means that LaTeX will be running `xindy` for sorting the glossaries **while latexing**. This is the delay you notice.

Comment: I do not know what is causing this delay, I disabled this package and tried but the problem is still there.

Comment: You have `\input{glossary}` in your document. We don't have that file, so we cannot test your document. It is not a MWE. It is also important to know how you run latex on your file. Do you run it from the command line? Or do you use some automatic system that runs makeindex or xindy automatically?

Comment: I am using texmaker in ubutnu 14.04. I also tried on command line with the make file too and then run again on texmaker but problem is there. For generating glossaries i ran the commands on command line; pdflatex main , makeglossaries main.

Comment: Following is the content of my glossary `%A \newacronym{aloha}{ALOHA}{Additive Link On-Line Hawaii System} %C \newacronym{capex}{CAPEX}{Capital Expenditure} \newacronym{cdma}{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access} \newacronym{csma}{CSMA}{Carrier Sense Multiple Access} %F \newacronym{fdma}{FDMA}{Frequency Division Multiple Access} %I \newacronym{isa}{ISA}{International Society of Automation } %O \newacronym{opex}{OPEX}{operational expenditure} %Q \newacronym{qos}{QoS}{Quality of Service}`

Comment: When you run `pdflatex main` from the command line, is the delay there also? If so, what point in the log is it?

Comment: From the command line its normal not slow, it shows some warnings also but those warnings are not that critical i think, these same warnings are also in GUI texmaker.

Comment: So then what command do you use in TeXmaker and how is it configured? I guess it also runs the `makeglossaries` command, could that be it?

Comment: I do not know wher ei can find this in texmaker GUI?

Comment: Depending on you OS, go to Preferenxes, or Tools > Options. You probably will see a screen with 4 icons on the left, titled Commands, Quick Build, Editor, and Shortcuts. Click on Quick Buld and look what is selected. If it is "User" then also tell us what is in the field under it.

Comment: In my settings User is not selected. But now since you told me i selected (ticked) it and the message under it is pasted below;                                                     latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %.aux|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|xdvi %.dvi